# Styling last item in a ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview, styling

is there any easy way to style the last item in a ListView control? Basicly need to append a class.

Cheers

Comment: Isn't listview a windows form control?

Comment: Is the number of children always the same and known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is

[:last-child](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html)

pesudo class.

But won't work in all browsers.

The best way is to add a css class to the last item in the listview and style it.

If you can use jQuery then you can use the

[:last-child](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild)

selector

Answer (score 4):

Comma separate a list of customers names. The last customer name will end with a dot.

Customer A, Customer B, Customer C.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvCustomers" runat="server">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <div id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></div>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval("CustomerName")<%# Container.DisplayIndex == (Container.BindingContainer.As<ListView>().DataSource.As<System.Collections.Generic.List<String>>().Count - 1) ? "." : ", " %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This uses an extension method 'As':

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns this object casted as a different type.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">A type</typeparam>
/// <param name="obj">An object</param>
/// <returns>A boolean value.</returns>
public static T As<T>(this object obj) where T : class
{
    if (obj == null) return null;

    return obj as T;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it working as

```
<%#(Container.DataItemIndex == dataList.Count - 1 ? "last" : "")%>
```

where datalist is the custom data class build in code behind and binded to listview.

Answer (score 1):

I do this kind of stuff in the ItemDataBound listview event.
But for that purpose I need to know what would be the type of the DataSource.

For example:

```
protected void LvFilters_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem item = e.Item as ListViewDataItem;
        if(item.DataItemIndex == ((YourDataSourceType)lvFilters.DataSource).Count - 1)
            e.Item.FindControl("Control's id here").Visible = false; // or whatever you wanna do about styling
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

phoenix's answer doesn't really answer the question, phoenix suggests styling the last item with a different css class, but how do you know which item is the last item? ListView has 
no LastItemTemplate.

You can use <%# Container.DisplayIndex %> to get your position in the current list. You can use Items.Count on the Control to get the total but combining these two things is slightly 
beyond my ASP.NET skills.